# How do I add a drop down menu icon?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, content-management-system

I have a question about adding some type of icon or indicator to the buttons that have drop down menus in my navigation. The menu looks good in all browsers with minor exceptions. The menu itself is built in an Ektron CMS. I have 7 buttons in my navigation, 5 of which have drop down menus. As you can see on my site I have a little right-arrow indicating which ones have drop downs. The arrow is a unicode character that luckily worked when adding it in the menu control in the CMS. I'm fairly happy with the results but I'm not sure if that was the best way to create the icon.

Is there a better, or more efficient way of creating this type of indicator? Is there a way in JavaScript to assign a symbol or icon only if there is a sub menu present?

Although my solution works, there is one issue that I'm having trouble solving. In IE7+, Chrome and Safari all of the buttons were perfectly aligned. In FireFox, the 2 buttons without drop down menus were 4px higher than the ones with drop downs. This occurred as soon as I added the unicode arrow character. I added a little CSS hack that corrects the issue in FF but now I have an issue in Chrome where the last two buttons are 4px lower than the rest. I'm not sure how to correct this problem efficiently.

Here is a link to my site. I appreciate any help you can provide.

http://www.clinicaltrialsummit.com/

Comment: Could you provide a clear example in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Here is the link to my jsfiddle. All of the buttons appear to be aligned vertically in jsfiddle but not on my live site. But you can see the unicode arrow that I'm using and that's my main question. Is there a better way of adding that type of menu indicator? http://jsfiddle.net/noahcg/bs9kd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this style:

```
#nav li a:last-child[href="http://www.healthtech.com/press.aspx"] { 
    padding: 16px 0.4em 0 
}
```

You have 14px default padding top, but the rule above sets padding of 16px for the last child with a specific href.

In your jsfiddle example there isn't this css rule.

You can use css arrows instead of UTF-8 symbol or use an icon, but I think that it's OK to use UTF-8 symbol like you do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding but I should have mentioned that the style you reference above is my css hack. I'll try to explain my reason behind using it.

I needed a way of singling out my last navigation button without being able to apply a class directly to the li. Since the menu itself is created using a control in my CMS the HTML markup is generated dynamically. I didn't want to use the :last-child pseudo class but I also needed a way of adding the extra px of padding only to FF. I knew that IE would ignore the :last-child. However, that's where I failed because it also added it in Chrome and I believe Safari. I can take the entire style out and that might help you see my problem better. You would see that the vertical alignment is correct in every browser except FF.

The entire alignment was perfect until I added in my UTF-8 character. That's when it became misaligned but only in FF.

How would I add a CSS arrow?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I just checked your link in FF and the shapes don't show up as arrows. They appear as trapezoids. They do appear as arrows in Chrome though.